# Why the submit button not works with I use jquery code in this page?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, submit

I have this code & the submit button not works if the jquery code is run.

When I comment the jquery code, the form is send perfectly.

Can you help me, please?

```html
 <div class="container">
  <form action="send.php" method="post">
  <div class="button-container">
   <div class="action-button shadow animate green">
    <label><input type="radio" name="color" value="verde" id="verde" style="visibility:hidden" required>PRESIONE EL BOTÓN VERDE</input></label>  
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button-container">
   <div class="action-button shadow animate red" >
    <label><input type="radio" name="color" value="rojo" id="rojo" style="visibility:hidden" required>PRESIONE EL BOTÓN ROJO</input></label> 
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-container" id="form" style="display:none">
   <div id="form-content">
    <div class="form-content-center">
     <img src="http://www.spring-gds.com/img/spring/logo.png" class="logo-responsive">
     <p>Para confirmar tu color y ganar un altavoz bluetooth Introduce:<p>
      <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required><br/>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required><br/>
      <!--<label><input type="radio" name="color" value="verde" id="verde" required>PRESIONE EL BOTÓN VERDE</input></label><br><br>
      <label><input type="radio" name="color" value="rojo" id="rojo" required>PRESIONE EL BOTÓN ROJO</input></label><br><br><br><br>-->
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="privacy" value="ok" required>Aceptas nuestra <a href="http://www.spring-gds.com/es/privacy-statement/" target="_blank">Política de privacidad</a></label><br/>    
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Confirmar" class="submit">
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
             $(".button-container").click(function(e){
                 e.preventDefault();
              var $more = $("#form").slideToggle("slow");
              $("body").animate({
                  scrollTop: $more.offset().top
              }, {
                  duration: 1200,
                  queue: false
              })
             });
         });

Comment: Your html is not correct, please, put the </form> tag in the correct place and try to run again

Comment: Put your code in question (edit it), not as unreadable comment

Answer (score 0):

That is because of `e.preventDefault();` in your JavaScript code. That line prevents the default behavior of the submit button.